# Visual studio(xamarin), unable to set project type to Android

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I have created a cross platform project that targets both IOs and Android with Xamarin using Visual Studio 2017(version 15.0). I have written some custom renderers that target android specifically on my work computer. What I am trying to accomplish is setting up debug breakpoints in any android related code, but the project dropdown only gives me IOS as an option. I can run the project on my android device.

As the figure shows, all the code is greyed out because of my precompiler conditional being set.

If I remove #if **ANDROID**
I can set break points and debug that way, but I'd like to be able to make use of intellisense. Anyone have any clue what I am missing to get this to work properly?

[image: figure 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by reloading the Android project.